# How to know html element is triggered or not

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm able trigger `mouseup` and `mousedown` events. For triggering I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("html").mouseup(function(){
       console.log("mouseup");
    });

    $("html").mousedown(function(){
       console.log("mousedown");
    });

});
```

My issue is, If I'm clicking on white space also my code was triggering. So, I want to trigger while user clicks on HTML elements only not on white screen. Is there any possibility to do this?

Comment: when do you want it to trigger?

Comment: When mouse was clicked on top of any html element (Except the white spaces)

Comment: Instead of html target specific dom elements

Comment: Instead of `$("html")` you can target other dom element

Comment: @LelioFaieta and @Yatendrasinh Joddha We have many dom elements. Is it good approach to write all dom elements instead of `html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was checking you question and realize that you want something generalized. So what I have done is, I have added a condition in which if the target is html, your further code will not execute(only event will be called).

```
$("html").mouseup(function(event){
   if(event.target !== $('html')[0]){
    console.log("mouseup");
   }
});

$("html").mousedown(function(event){
    if(event.target !== $('html')[0]){
    console.log("mousedown");
   }
});
```

Comment: I've tried as you said but i'm getting same response as i got previous

Answer (score 0):

Write now you adding the events on the whole html div. This means everything wrapped within `<html> ... </html>` tags will respond to that event. Fix it to the name of the tag of the particular div you want to respond to the event.

For Example for a button it will become

```
 $('button').on('mouseup', () => {
      console.log('mouse up on button')
 })`
```

Comment: Instead of button is there any possibility to give any generalized tag which is applicable for any dom element like button, lable and other

Comment: You can name it whatever you want to. The key thing over here is that everything wrapped within that div will respond to the event. Even the whitespace that is a part of it. So don't put the event on the whole html page. Try using html classes to add events on a group.

Comment: Ho okay thnq :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `*` selector for it.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //$("html").find("*").mouseup(function(e) { or
    $("html *").mouseup(function(e) {
        console.log("mouseup");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
    //$("html").find("*").mousedown(function(e) { or
    $("html *").mousedown(function(e) {
        console.log("mousedown");
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution